# Sort entire data with tablesorter jQuery

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter for sorting my tables. But it seems to sort only the visible data in my table. Suppose I have 100 records numbered 1 to 100 and I display only 10 records at a time,  then when I sort a particular column, only those 10 records are sorted ascendingly(1->10) or descendingly(10->1). But I need the entire data to be sorted(i.e in the table I should get 1->10 or 100->91). How is that possible?

This is the code I use for sorting:

```
 $(".tableSort").tablesorter({
    cssAsc:'asc',
    cssDesc:'desc',
    sortList:[[0,0]],
    widgets:['zebra']
 });
```

**EDIT:**
I had noticed now that when I move to the next page, i.e, the second page, there I get the numbers as 90-81 (the entire data has been sorted in descending order). And When I move back to the first page, I get the numbers as 100-91. But Initially it is displayed as 10-1. What is the reason? How do I resolve this?

Comment: how are you displaying 10 records at a time and how are you hiding the remaining 90?

Comment: I initially hide all the tr. And then display 10 by 10 using a for loop based on the page numbers.

Comment: Why aren't you using the [tablesorter pager addon](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html)?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a tag and not display it like

```
var table = $('<table></table>');
```

the add all the data to that tag and then do

```
table.tablesorter({
    cssAsc:'asc',
    cssDesc:'desc',
    sortList:[[0,0]],
    widgets:['zebra']
 });
```

The reason it is sorting what is displayed, is because your selecting the table that is displayed.

Comment: I gave an id to the table and changed the code like this:  `var appln_tbl=$("table#disburement_application");
  appln_tbl.tablesorter({
  cssAsc:'asc',
  cssDesc:'desc',
  sortList:[[0,0]],
  widgets:['zebra'],
  headers: { 
  0: {sorter:'alphanumericHeaderSort'}, 
  1: {sorter:'alphanumericHeaderSort'},
  2: {sorter:'descriptionHeaderSort'},
  3: {sorter:'commaDigit'},
  4: {sorter:'digit'},
  5: {sorter:'descriptionHeaderSort'},
  6: {sorter:'commaDigit'},
  7: {sorter:'dateheaderSort'},
  8: {sorter:'dateheaderSort'} 
 } 
 });` [assuming this is what you meant],but I get the same problem.